# JavaScript Dateobject Increment goes wrong

Tags: javascript, date

I want to increment the year-value of a given date, but this goes wrong.

this is my code:

```
var endDate = entry.start;
endDate.setDate(endDate.getFullYear() + 5);
```

and for comparison the output (console.log) is:

Date {Thu Jun 30 2011 11:30:10 GMT+0200}

Date {Tue Dec 06 2016 11:30:10 GMT+0100}

as you can see, it also incremented the month and Day.
What am I missing?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the year only, using the `setYear` method:

```
endDate.setYear(endDate.getFullYear() + 5);
```

Using `setDate(getFullYear()+5)` you add 5 + (year of the date) days to the date value of `endDate`

Answer (score 2):

You're adding 2016 days to it, not modifying the year, which is 5 and a half year.